# Video edit framework in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, video-processing

Is there any framework that can edit videos in objective-c. Any help is welcome.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`libavcodec`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) for A/V manipulation. It's a C based API, so it'll look different than the rest of your code, but it'll work just fine. The documentation is sparse though.

If you're not targeting iOS devices, Quicktime is still there.

If you are targeting iOS devices, the new [`AVFoundation`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html) framework may be able to help you.

Comment: I think this will be the solution. One more thing. Do you think with AVFoundation I can cut the videos?

Comment: I only have personal experience with `ffmpeg`/`libavcodec`, but from looking through the API for `AVFoundation`, it looks like there are facilities for video editing (I'm also guessing that the new iMovie app uses at least some of `AVFoundation` internally). For some better guidance you might consider watching the session videos from WWDC this year; I remember seeing a couple that focused on using `AVFoundation`.